# Static object in struct

Tags: c++, object, struct, static

I have class `A` with method `display()`. I create a struct `B` with a static variable of type object `A`:

```
class A{
public :
    void display()
    {
        cout << "in A " << endl;
    }
};
typedef struct B{
    static A a;
} bb;

//B::a.display();
int main() {
    bb b;
    bb::a.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I get an error when try to access `a`.

How can I define a static object in this case?

Comment: What is the error message, did you use a `using`-directive or `using`-declarations to make `std`'s namespace symbols available ?

Comment: I think it just declare object A. B::a.display(); not work because undefined reference to `B::a'.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Where?

Comment: @Rerito could you show more specific about using-directive or using-declarations

Comment: @MemoryLeak, here is an article that should enlighten you about namespaces in C++ : http://winterdom.com/dev/cpp/nspaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `static A a;` but did not define it. Add the following line before `int main()` and it'll link successfully:

```
A B::a;
```

Comment: Since no constructor for `A` is defined, won't the compiler automatically call a default constructor to initialize a ?

Comment: @Rerito: Yes. Doesn't mean you don't have to define it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Tested on Ideone without adding anything except a `using`-directive : http://ideone.com/0LkbNE. Why did it work ?

Comment: @Rerito: No access to data members. Therefore no _odr-use_. [Here's the real testcase](http://ideone.com/VwP6Pc).